# QGIS page setup Size

Tags: qgis

I've got another problem with QGIS, I'm using the latest Version Essen, as well as teh latest LTS Wien.
I'am not able to change the size of my print Composer page.
In the menue I can choose all options, but this options are not taken in the composer. There the sheet is always in DIN A4 landscape.

Does somebody have an idea what I'm making wrong?
A colegue, installed QGIS and during me teaching him how to use it I told him, that this was a bug, and he told me it would on his computer.

Yours
Riker

Comment: sorry, I just solved the problem.

Comment: For all, who have the same problem: there are two lokations where the page size can be determindes, it did not work in the printing setup (as in ArcGIS), but it works if it ist determindes in teh right menue tab "composition"